# How to handle the require syntax in custom loader of webpack

Tags: json, webpack, require, loader, webpack-file-loader

I am encountering a problem with handling the 'require' syntax in webpack's custom loader.
I have an src fold and a dist fold, use pug to transform an HTML file by webpack from src to dist, and I need to require a json file in my pug file like this,

```
html(lang="en")
  head
   meta(name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes")
   link(rel="manifest", href=require("../manifest.json"))
```

and inside the json file, I need require an image file, like this,

```
{
  "name": "Webm Maker",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "short_name": "Webm Maker",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen48.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png"
  }]
}
```

I used file-loader to create a json file to dist directly, but it was irrational, it couldn't resolve the src route in the json file.
Then I tried to use a custom format file to resolve the src problem like this:

```
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes")
    link(rel="manifest", href=require("../manifest.prejson"))
```

then, I set the webpack like this

```
...
{
   test: /\.prejson$/i,
   use: [{
     loader: 'file-loader'
   }, {
     loader: path.join(__dirname, 'utils', 'prejson-to-json.js'),
   }]
}
...
```

And the custom format file manifest.prejson

```
-{
    name: "Webm Maker",
    display: "fullscreen",
    orientation: "landscape",
    short_name: "Webm Maker",
    icons: [{
        src: require("./images/images.jpeg"),
        sizes: "48x48",
        type: "image/png"
    }]
 }
```

At this time, file-loader resolved the image route and generated an image file in the dist fold. However, I don't know how to handle the require syntax in the .prejson file, in the custom loader js file 'prejson-to-json.js', I coded like this,

```
module.exports = function (source, map) {
  console.log('source', source);
  this.callback(null, source, map);
  return source;
};
```

the image src route was still like 'require(...)';
So how can I resolve it let the output can replace the require syntax with a correct route that points at the dist image file?